# Started playing with selenium, somethings wrong with get by css method

Tags: python, css, selenium

i started playing with selenium, since i practiced bs4 a lot. 
So i imported selenium, added chrome driver, it opens everything properly - so far so good!

problem came when i decided to pick some elemenit by css selector and i did it on this site like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shop.foretagsakvarium.se/product/aquamedic-xenia-100")
x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("main#main-content span.amount")
```

and instead of element output i got this:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b7719f12f537bf845f6e82e58d391d3", element="0.27049897880791063-1")>
>>> [10348:7764:0116/020724.433:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10348:7764:0116/020724.434:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10348:7764:0116/020724.434:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10348:7764:0116/020724.434:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

what and where i did wrong? have i frogot to import something? Everything that i imported is:

```
>>> import selenium
>>> from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: This seems an issue caused by latest chrome driver, have a look at issue on github: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5189

Comment: thank you. What i should do, use older version of chromedriver or? What do you reccomend?

Comment: In that issue, someone just changes to an older version and gets worked. So although without testing, I think that could be a solution.

Comment: tnx mate, cheerz!

Comment: Use the latest chromedriver, it is fixed

Comment: Thanks  mate, i downloaded mozzila webdriver for playing around now, your input helped me greatly!

this is latest version: ChromeDriver 2.34

Comment: chromedriver 2.35 is out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the ChromeDriver but the chrome version 63 has bugs. Downgrading your chrome version should fix the issue.

Downgrade from here : https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

( You can use version < 63 )

Comment: thank you, iit solved it  :)  its useful to have it here! cheers!

Comment: Why do you say `chrome version 63 has bugs` ? Do you have a [**`MCVE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, Yes i have faced the similar issue. Upon searching through, i found Chrome v63 has some issues in ShaderCache. And as suggested, downgrading to a previous version (v62) fixed the issue for me.

Please refer to here : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5189